# CSS dropdown responsive sub menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newbie and learning about CSS code. I want to add the dropdown submenu in the dashboard menu but I don't have exprience about css dropdown responsive menu and don't know how to apply this, bellow are the code that I found from other resources and I add the dashboard menu and the submenu inside it. This code can be run in mobile.

When I add the dropdown submenu inside the dashboard, The css do not disappear when I navigate it. Here are the codes:

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

```css
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
 
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}
 
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}
 
/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #111;}
 
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}





@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
 

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a>   
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry. What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: My expected behavior is I want the sub menus "profile", "change password" and "other" hide inside the menu "dashboard" using css and responsive in mobile.

Comment: It does — not — work in your `HTML` structure. You want to be `.hidden` a `child` of `#dashboard`. This does — not — work `.hidden{display:none}
    #dashboard:hover ~ .hidden{display:block}`. Then you can do `.hidden{display:none}
    #dashboard:hover  .hidden{display:block}`.

Comment: Yes Thanks, I am able to hide the child of #dashboard now and the child was disappear, now I want to make it appear when I navigate the #dashboard menu, how do I apply this css?

Comment: Look at my answer. %)P

Answer (score 0):

I show you here how I meant with a `parent` structure.

`:hover` is just for demo case.

You can change to Javascript `click`.

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

```css
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
 
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}
 
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}
 
/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #111;}
 
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
.hidden{display:none}
#dashboard:hover + .hidden{display:block !important}

.hidden{display:none}
.upper:hover .hidden{display:block}



@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
 

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="upper"><a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a>   
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes Thanks, I am able to hide the child of #dashboard now and the child was disappear, now I want to make it appear when I navigate the #dashboard menu, how do I apply this css?

Comment: You have to change the `HTML` too. Look at this answer. %)P

Comment: I try to make the drop down menu become vertical. I put the code at below answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*Style for dropdown links*/

.topnav>li:hover ul a {
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}


/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

.topnav>li:hover ul a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

.topnav>li ul {
  display: none;
}


/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

.topnav>li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}


/*Prevent text wrapping*/

.topnav>li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

.topnav>ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

The sub menu became vertical but the background black color is too long:
Below are the image of my problem: [dropdownmenucss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaXuG.jpg)